# runtime array assignment for an array of arrays

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I apparently have a tragic grasp of memory allocation and arrays. What I want is quite simple, there's an array of arrays, the array contains an interval within it. My question is even though I assign a new array below *int arr_letter[2]* and assign it to *arr[arr_index]*, on every iteration ALL the values: arr[0], arr[1], arr[2] ...., get assigned to what's in arr[arr_index].

I suppose because of the way I declared int * arr[26], i'd need an analogous array for the interval [x,y] every  time I want to add a new element to this array, instead of doing what I'm doing, which is over-writing the array. But I was wondering if someone has a better way?

```
int * partitionLabels(char * S, int * returnSize)
{

    int * arr[26];
    memset(arr, 0, 26*sizeof(arr[0]));
    
    int idx_start = 0;
    int idx_end = 0;

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while(S[i] != '\0')
    {
        // this populates all the intervals
    //  printf("%c %d\n ", S[i], S[i]-97);
        int arr_index = S[i]-97;
        if(arr[arr_index] == 0)
        {
            // S[i]-97 is the integer representation of the character

            idx_start = i;
            idx_end = i;
            j = i;
            while(S[j] != '\0')
            {
                if(S[j] == S[i]) idx_end = j;       
                j++;
            }
            int arr_letter[2] = {idx_start, idx_end}; // problem is HERE
            arr[arr_index] = arr_letter;
        }
        i++;
    }

    int main()
    {
        char * s = "ababcbacadefegdehijhklij";
    
        int returnSize = 0;
    
        partitionLabels(s, &returnSize);
    }
```

Comment: You know that arr[26] and int arr_letter[2] are only valid inside partitionLabels(), right?  Also:  Q: is 26 a good "max size", or do you think you might need more than 26?  If so, have you considered just creating a linked list?

Comment: 26 is good. I won't be returning arr[26] or arr_letter[2], they will be used later for returnSize however. I'd just like a way to generate a 2 member array, then assign it to arr[arr_index]. And more importantly, cure my forsaken understanding

Comment: Personally, I'd just declare `int arr[2][26]`, and declare it *outside* of "partitionLabels()".

Comment: I think the problem is even simpler than you might think. it's just when I say "int arr_letter[2] = { ... }", what's happening is it's using the same memory address for the variable, and arr will assign this to all the elements. What I need is unique memory assignment for arr_letter[2] each time I call it. Which makes me think it's better to use another pointer? lol.... brain fog (it really is a rookie problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're not *using* memory allocation. :-) Your `arr` array is an array of pointers to integers, but there is no place to store the integers declared. When you do `int arr_letter[2] = {idx_start, idx_end}`, you are initializing an automatic variable on the stack with the values `idx_start` and `idx_end`, then assigning to the current index in `arr[]`. But this value, being on the stack, is ephemeral. It won't outlast the scope at worst and at best will be re-used on the next iteration. I'd recommend, if I understand your use case, declaring `int arr[26][2]` which allocates two integers for each of the 26 indices in `arr`. Then you'd set `arr[arr_index][1] = idx_start` and `arr[arr_index][2] = idx_end`. (Actually, if it were me, I'd define a `struct interval { int start; int end };` and then make an array of those, `struct interval arr[26]` and `arr[arr_index].start=idx_start` and `arr[arr_index].end=idx_end` but that may be further along than where you are.) Also as someone pointed out, `arr` disappears when the function returns. Not sure how you intend to access it.

Comment: but say I did want to use memory allocation - it appears that memset did not do what I thought it would do for me. The structure is a good idea.

Comment: Maybe. What did you think `memset` did? All it does is write zeroes into already allocated memory. `malloc` is what allocates memory.